# How can I get rid of the endless while loop in C?

Tags: c, function, if-statement, while-loop

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
double a, b, c;
int total_Result;

    while(1) {
        printf("please enter 3 number\n");
        total_Result = scanf("%lf %lf %lf", &a, &b, &c);
        printf("totalresult = %d\n", total_Result);
    
        if(total_Result == 3) {
            
            printf("your numbers: a = %f, b = %f, c = %f\n", a, b, c);
            break;
        }
        else {
            puts("you should enter the number");
            
        }
    }
    
    return 0;

}
```

When we accidentally enter a string expression instead of a number in the above code block, it automatically gives an error and enters an infinite loop. How can I solve this problem without using any new methods or functions. What are your recommendations?

When I enter 3 numbers, the program runs without error. However, when I enter 2 numbers and 1 character, it goes into an infinite loop and I don't want that. I want him to check the numbers again.

Comment: Use `fgets`. Coupled with `sscanf` if you wish. That is, read the input as a string, then parse it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove invalid data from the input buffer. For example

```
while(1) {
    printf("please enter 3 number\n");
    total_Result = scanf("%lf %lf %lf", &a, &b, &c);
    printf("totalresult = %d\n", total_Result);

    if ( total_Result == EOF ) break;

    if(total_Result == 3) {
        
        printf("your numbers: a = %f, b = %f, c = %f\n", a, b, c);
        break;
    }
    else {
        scanf( "%*[^\n]" );
        puts("you should enter the number");
        
    }
}
```

Comment: what is the meaning of "%*[^\n]" ?

Comment: @omerllrd It reads all characters from the input buffer until the new line character is encountered. The read characters are discarded.